# Jupyter Notebook resizing Images with div stops working after a few cells

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Resizing images in Jupyter like this was working great(so cool) for a few markdown cells.

```
<div>
   <img src="attachment:5508bbd7-3504-4633-b5d3-65c99eb3e027.png" width="300">
</div>
```

and then for no reason, it stopped and no matter what I add or change it just gives me this
[image]

I can still copy and paste images into the cells BUT I can't use div to resize anymore.

I tried this too and got the same 'Image'

```
<img src="attachment:1689685b-e863-4f9a-aa7a-1a5a0430ad71.png" width="200">
```

I'd appreciate any advice, thanks!!